# How to enhance the for loop to click any random calculator numbers?

Tags: javascript, testcomplete

The following piece of code will click the calculator buttons from 1 to 9 (static number ranges) in TestComplete automation tool scripting. I would like to enhance this for loop to make it click any number combination like 456 or 987 any combination of numbers. Can some one help me on this?

```
//Click Calculator buttons 1-9
for (i=1; i<=9; i++)
{
   alias.Window("Button", i).ClickButton(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
  intStartIndex = 0;
  intEndIndex = 9;
  // Click three buttons
  for (i=1; i <= 3; i++)
  {
    btnIndex = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (intEndIndex - intStartIndex) + intStartIndex);  
    alias.Window("Button", btnIndex.toString()).ClickButton(); 
  }
```